# Google Places API vs Google Maps results

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I see some results on Google Maps but its not coming through Google Places API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=my_api_key&sensor=false&radius=50000&location=40.338254%2C-74.585292&keyword=storybook+land

whereas google maps shows

Storybook Land, Black Horse Pike, Egg Harbor Township, NJ, United States

Why this discrepancy? Is it not that Google Places API will show the exact results of Google Maps?

I observed these kind of discrepancies in few other results also.

Can somebody throw some light?

Comment: I am finding establishments using Google Maps that I cannot find using the Places API even with the textsearch option. If anyone can shed some light on why or how to get similar results using Places I would be appreciative.

Comment: 6 years later having the same problem. If google can provide a solution I'd love to use an "intelligent" textsearch API, but till then scraping seems the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must ask google about the way they get their results, but I don't think that maps.google.com is a simple implementation of the Maps-API/Services.

However,  [textSearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) will give you the result: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=yourKey&sensor=false&radius=50000&location=40.338254%2C-74.585292&query=storybook+land

Comment: Yes. textsearch gives whereas nearbysearch doesn't. What's the reason behind this?