# Does Google Places store information on internet access (wlan, termina, no, ecc.)?

Tags: r, google-places-api

I used this query in R

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rcurl)
key = MY_OWN_KEY (replace with your Google API key)
url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid="
place_id = 'ChIJy5DkgiBiLxMRFr1YqGYxF30'
url2 = gsub(" ", "", paste0(url1, place_id, "&key=", key))
doc <- fromJSON(url2)
names(doc$result)

[1] "address_components"         "adr_address"                "formatted_address"         
[4] "formatted_phone_number"     "geometry"                   "icon"                      
[7] "id"                         "international_phone_number" "name"                      
[10] "opening_hours"              "photos"                     "place_id"                  
[13] "rating"                     "reference"                  "reviews"                   
[16] "scope"                      "types"                      "url"                       
[19] "utc_offset"                 "vicinity"                   "website"
```

to get details from a bar. There is no field for `internet_access`. Can you confirm me that Google does not store this kind of information for bar? Anyway, if I search for bar wifi in Google Maps it does find bars with wifi. Is it using some internal information not available through the API?

Thanks,
Jacopo

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39432670/5977215), and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21386882/5977215) - In summary, the API does not provide the same results as you get in Google Maps

Comment: Also, my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package might make the API calls easier for you.